# Oracle Table cannot be found via EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am just wondering, why i am getting data, but cannot delete it?
The error is

> ORA-06550: Row 4, Column 9:
>
> > PL/SQL: ORA-00942: Table or View not found

```
var entries = await _db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.OBJECT_ID == objectId).ToListAsync();
                _db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entries);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Corresponding class is

```
[Table("PC_NS_REC_MSG_LIVE", Schema = "ENERGYDATASTORE")]
public class PC_NS_REC_MSG_LIVE : IReceivedMessage
{

}
```

It worked before, but suddenly this statement cannot be executed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still use dotnet core 2 and EF core 2 ? 
The oracle ef provider does only support ef core as time of writing (2nd April 2020).. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/

This could be an issue...
[image]

Comment: correct. for oracle, i am using everything core related  < 3.0.0 :-/ this is really not great, but it still works, up to now

Comment: Yep - it keeps us as well on .net core 2 yet - which is really annoying. May you mark my answer as correct then?

Comment: well, it did work before, yesterday, with ef core. 2.2.X. it must not be an issue with the current version. maybe another problem occured which i am not aware of?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but our team decided to stick with asp.net core 2.2 and ef core 2.2. for the affected services. But would be intresting, if someone did get it running with EF Core 2.2. and dotnet core 3.X

Comment: i was able to resolve the issue. Thanks for input. Hopefully, Oracel EF Core 3.x will be release soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue.
I switched my query (at another method) from

```
dbContext.Set<T>.ToListAsync();
```

to

```
dbContext.T.FromSql("sqlQueryString").ToListAsync();
```

After that, I was not able to use any other `dbContext.Set<T>` or execute `DbCommands`.

The solution for that was to change the above statement to

```
dbContext.T.FromSql("sqlQueryString").AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Now i am able to use everything as before. Hope this might help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the Oracle catalog is case-sensitive.  And if you use delimited mixed-case identifiers when creating tables, you must use delimited mixed-case identifiers when querying them.  If you use un-delimited identifiers when creating tables, Oracle converts the identifiers to all upper case, and converts identifiers in queries to upper case to when matching catalog items.

So

```
CREATE TABLE "Foo" ...
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Foo ...
```

create two different tables with different names.  The first one is named "Foo" and the second one "FOO".  And the query

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

will query the second one.